# Swift ios print a document in A4

Tags: ios, swift

I have this working code for printing:

```
let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
printInfo.jobName = "Title"
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
printController.printInfo = printInfo
printController.printingItem = myItem
printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

When I execute this code, almost all is Ok, but the option of Paper format is not A4, is letter. How can I change that ?

Comment: See the documentation for `UIPrintPaper`. It answers your question.